# Python python_keyring package - Upgrade of Python has broken keyring

Tags: python, python-keyring

I have upgrade from python 3.9.6 to 3.10.5 and kept thankfully the old version. This is on a Win-64 machine so should be using the WinVault backend (default)

I have copied all the site_packages from 3.9.6 to 3.10.5 (except for those already installed by the newer version)

Running **keyring** under 3.10.05 the error is

```
keyring.errors.NoKeyringError: No recommended backend was available. Install a recommended 3rd party backend package; or, install the keyrings.alt package if you want to use the non-recommended backends. See https://pypi.org/project/keyring for details.
```

I can run the same code under 3.9.6 with no problems.

Running

```
python -c "import keyring.util.platform_; print(keyring.util.platform_.config_root())"
```

or

```
python -c "import keyring.util.platform_; print(keyring.util.platform_.data_root())"
```

under either version is producing locations that don't really exist. I have created a keyringrc.cfg file with a `keyring.backends.Windows.WinVaultKeyring` line but it doesn't seem to do anything

I don't mind having to re-enter keyring passwords but would like to get this working under 3.10.5.

Ideas

Answer (score 0):

This has eventually turned out to be needs to upgrade cffi which has fixed the problem.